# C program - Process don't invoke after sending SIGTERM signal

Tags: c, signals, fork, wait

I am new in using signals on C programming.

I wrote two simple source codes child.c and parent.c in order to demonstrate my issue.

child.c

```
void errorHandler(char* message);
void sigterm_handler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void* ptr);

int main(){

    struct sigaction action1;
    memset(&action1, 0, sizeof(action1));
    action1.sa_sigaction = sigterm_handler;
    action1.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if(sigaction(SIGTERM, &action1, NULL) != 0)
        errorHandler("Signal sigterm_handler registration failed");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        printf("%d\n", i);
        if(i == 5){

            if(raise(SIGSTOP)!= 0)
                errorHandler("Raise SIGSTOP failed");
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void errorHandler(char* message){

    printf("Error: %s: %s\n", message, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void sigterm_handler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void* ptr){

    printf("Child: Process %d finishes\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

parent.c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int status;
    pid_t mem;
    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child == 0){

        char* arr[] = {"./child", NULL};
        execv(arr[0], arr);
    }

    else if(child > 0){

        mem = child;
        waitpid(mem, &status, WUNTRACED);
    }

    if(WSTOPSIG(status)){

        printf("Sending SIGTERM to child\n");
        kill(mem, SIGTERM);
        waitpid(mem, &status, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run parent.c, the program print into stdout:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Sending SIGTERM to child
```

but then the program get stuck, probably because sigterm_handler don't invoke, instead of printing "Child: Process *** finishes".

I tried to read on the linux manual page but I still can't to figure it out.

Can anyone please explain to me what is causing this issue?

Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: `printf` is not a signal-safe function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But this does _not_ mean, that it may not be used in a signal handler. You just have to make sure, that no other stdio functions, that operate on the same stream, can be interrupted by that signal handler.

Comment: @Ctx no, `printf` cannot be used in a signal handler, ever. Just for starting, `printf` can call `malloc` which itself isn't signal safe, and a signal handler can be invoked while the stdio buffers are flushed upon exiting. Not even `snprintf` or `dprintf` are safe to use from a signal handler.

Comment: And no, `exit(3)` cannot be called from a signal handler, either. Only `_exit(2)` is signal-safe, but that may terminate the process before the `printf` message is actually printed out ;-)

Comment: @mosvy That's untrue, it is a valid option to block signal delivery in the main program when calling non-async-safe functions and use the same, such as printf(), in signal handlers.

Comment: @Ctx Yes, it's perfectly true. Good luck with implementing your "valid option", since 99% of library functions are NOT signal-safe. And as I already told you, you can't do anything about the global destructors, as those that flush the stdio buffers upon `exit(3)` or returning from `main()`.

Comment: @mosvy If you made sure that the signal handler is not called while inside such a library function, nothing bad can happen. The "rules of thumb", that you convey here, may be a safe bet for novice programmers, but it's only half of the truth, when digging deeper.

Comment: regarding: `execv(arr[0], arr);`  this should be followed by: `perror( "execv failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error: %s: %s\n", message, strerror(errno));` and similar error messages:  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s: %s\n", message, strerror(errno));`

Comment: do your self a favor,  when in a signal handler, call: `write( 1, message, messageLen );` rather than the 'risky' function: `printf()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the child process, that calls

```
if(raise(SIGSTOP) != 0)
```

is *still stopped*, when the parent here

```
kill(mem, SIGTERM);
```

sends the signal `SIGTERM`. The signal is not lost, but is still pending at the child's process and will be delivered, as soon as the process continues to run. You can achieve that by issuing

```
kill(mem, SIGCONT);
```

directly after sending the `SIGTERM`. Then, the child will resume to run, the signal will be delivered and the handler will be executed, printing the diagnostic message and exiting the process.